# Why isn't PyCharm's autocomplete working for libraries I install?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

PyCharm's autocomplete isn't working for installed libraries.  I have the following code:

```py
from boto.emr.connection import EmrConnection
conn = EmrConnection(aws_keys.access_key_id, aws_keys.secret_key)
```

I want the editor to tell me what methods I have available to me when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

The boto library is installed in my environment, but it doesn't seem to be detected by PyCharm. How can I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You've installed the 3rd-party library into a virtualenv, but PyCharm doesn't know about that by default.  If nothing is specified, it will choose the system Python install as the interpreter.  You need to go into the project settings and configure the interpreter to point at the virtualenv.  PyCharm will then index the interpreter and allow you to autocomplete.

[image: Project interpreter settings]

The virtualenv may be auto-detected in the dropdown menu on the left.  If it is not, click the gear to the right, click "Add local", and select `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python` (or `\Path\to\virtualenv\Scripts\python.exe` on Windows).

Answer (score 4):

The above answer didn't work for me, because I wasn't able to find any project related setting in my setting,and the python Interpreter was empty.

The solution was to delete .idea file, from project root, close Pychram then go to project directory and open it with Pycharm:

$pycharm-professional     or $pycharm-professional .

when it lunch a pop up window on the bottom right will appear and as you the following
[image: pop-up-1]

select configure python interpreter then a new window must appear:
[image: pop-up-2]

chose to use Pipenv as your interpreter or any other solution that is for your case.

Now the Project setting should appear again in Pycharm setting, and the recommendation must be already working.