# Why PyCharm not show autocomplete list

Tags: python, pycharm

I have installed the `PIL` library using `pip` like this:

```
pip install Pillow
```

and it's working fine also showing library path in interrupter PyCharm Options.

But Autocomplete is not working, I tried to turn off the Power Save Mode and added custom virtual env, but it's still not working.

[image: Have a look Image]

Any idea why it does not work?

So it's now showing sub methods :

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
im.rotate(45).show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't PyCharm's autocomplete working for libraries I install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677670/why-isnt-pycharms-autocomplete-working-for-libraries-i-install)

Comment: Yes this is what i defined that virtual env also not working.

Comment: How do you expect PyCharm to know what type of object `mandeep` is?

Comment: I have seen PIL Library have show option when you use Image.open("ad") but it's now showing me when i type (.)

Here are document i am looking but how do i know what methods provider by pillow library ? or i have to look documents every time.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/overview.html#image-display

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PyCharm doesn't know the type of `im` as the library has no type hints for `Image.open()`. So I decided to set local type hint like this:

```
your_image = Image.open(path_to_image) # type: Image.Image
your_image.now_shows_list = True
```

For complete reference look at [JetBrains type hints documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that:

- PIL.Image is a module (normally lowercase)
- The module contains a function called open()
- open() returns a Type of PIL.Image.Image
- PyCharm does not realise it returns this type unless you tell it (I don't why).

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/handbook/tutorial.html#using-the-image-class

To avoid clashes with my project on the name "Image", as well as to stay Pep8 and adhere to google's style guide, I opted for:

```
    from PIL import Image as PilImage

    my_image: PilImage.Image = PilImage.open("my_image.png")
    my_image.show()
```

Running on python 3.8.2