# How to get code completion for Tensorflow in PyCharm?

Tags: python, module, tensorflow, pycharm, code-completion

I have installed the tensorflow module and it works in PyCharm. However, I want it to have code completion. Currently I do this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant("Hello, Tensorflow!")
```

However, PyCharm doesn't suggest or autocomplete functions when I type 'tf'
Is this possible to be done automatically or am I missing something?

I am using Windows 10. Tensorflow is installed natively.

Comment: Found a link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677670/why-isnt-pycharms-autocomplete-working-for-libraries-i-install

Comment: @CoolqB I have the correct interpreter I'm pretty sure; tensorflow runs natively. I don't know anything about a 'virtualenv'

Comment: Code completion works, but it's extremely slow for larger libraries like tensorflow or numpy. It should be fixed in PyCharm 2017.1 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21180 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out whether you are not at the bottom of editor when working on 2 or more monitors. Popups (including autocompletion ones) vanish there. See this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85749 JetBranins bug - old, still open (and vote it up).

Answer (score -1):

This is working now (tested on Win7 with PyCharm version 2017.2.4):

[image: pycharm_tf]