# Pycharm not auto-completing some modules

Tags: python, pycharm

I was working with opencv in python.

Whenever I use `import cv2` and then use any of the functions say `cv2.imread()` pycharm does not autocomplete the function.

It does so for other modules. Don't know how to solve it.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677670/why-isnt-pycharms-autocomplete-working-for-libraries-i-install) but am not able to find any virtual environment.

I used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783956/how-to-install-opencv-3-1-for-python-3-5-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) method to get pycharm working on my linux system

Edit : I don't know if this helps but

The path of the`cv2` module is `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Pycharm Project interpreter path is `/usr/bin/python3.5`