# Autocomplete does not always work on Pycharm

Tags: python, autocomplete, pygame, pycharm

I'm starting to use Pycharm, creating a test with Pygame.

I notice that some Pygame methods do not appear in Pycharm AutoComplete.

For example, if I want to put a `pygame.mask.from_surface ()`, typing `pygame.mas` will not do anything. But if I manually complete `mask` and press`.`, then the auto-complete `from_surface ()` appears correctly.

Ex:

```
import pygame
car = pygame.image.load("car.png").convert_alpha()
car_mask = pygame.mas    #### .... here, Pycharm should already show autocomplete
```

This also appears for other situations, for example, if I want to use `car.get_rect()`, it does not appear there anymore after typing `car.`

Here are my project settings:
[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: On my system `pygame.image` is a `.pyd` file. (IE: a Windows .dll)  So I do not find it surrising that PyCharm can provide less information about it.

Comment: Ticket in PyCharms' issue tracker: PY-30459.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the problem that you are facing but I found another solution that may help. Found it here : [Why isn't PyCharm's autocomplete working for libraries I install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677670/why-isnt-pycharms-autocomplete-working-for-libraries-i-install?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

You've installed the 3rd-party library into a virtualenv, but PyCharm doesn't know about that by default. If nothing is specified, it will choose the system Python install as the interpreter. You need to go into the project settings and configure the interpreter to point at the virtualenv. PyCharm will then index the interpreter and allow you to autocomplete.

Comment: pygame is already in my project settings. I edited my question and put a screenshot.

Comment: Did anyone got any answer?

Answer (score 1):

Solved downloading the [PyCharm Early Access Program](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) version.