# SmartType Code Completion for Python in PyCharm for Google Cloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jetbrains-ide, google-cloud-python

I tried but I am not able to find any SmartType Code Completion plugin for Google Cloud in PyCharm that can be used with Python.

Is anyone aware of any Google or JetBrains provided SmartType Code Completion plugin for Google Cloud in PyCharm that can be used with Python?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific plugin from GCP for the autocompletion of Google Cloud in PyCharm. To get autocomplete on PyCharm for 3rd party libraries you can check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28679116/8935548) for the steps needed.