# PyCharm Isn't Autocompleting OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm having a similar problem to this: [Why isn't PyCharm's autocomplete working for libraries I install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677670/why-isnt-pycharms-autocomplete-working-for-libraries-i-install) but the accepted answer isn't working for me because I'm probably misinterpreting it. **To clarify, the difference is that SOME of my installed libraries DO autocomplete, but not OpenCV.**

I've been playing with Py and OpenCV for a few days and finally got fed up with it not autocompleting. It's driving me crazy.

[I tried to add a new virtual env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBMBJ.png) to the Project Interpreter **(as the linked post suggests)** but it doesn't work. The main thing I know that I don't understand is where the path is supposed to go, *exactly*. It defaults to `\..\venv\`, but when I make a new project that path is filled with the default virtualenv by PyCharm? And then it's upset because that path is not empty?

Okay so I make a new folder and new environment there and now I have two `Lib` folders and two `Scripts` and it's just a disaster. Okay so I delete the contents of my `venv` folder and then populate that with a new environment. Same problem.

I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't make sense of it. I tried to follow the [JetBrains tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env) but I'm clearly missing something.

.

I have tried to make a new virtual environment, I have tried to make a new project, and I have tried deleting my `venv` folder contents and making a new virtualenv in settings. [Here's my interpreter settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l06Pw.png)

I have no idea what I'm doing, please explain in great detail. Thank you and I'm sorry if you believe this to be a repost/spam.

Comment: It seems to be a known issue of PyCharm: [Code completion doesn't work for cv2 module : PY-35691](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35691/Code-completion-doesnt-work-for-cv2-module)

Comment: Thank you. Will try to downgrade to 4.5.4.60 I guess. Good to know I'm not quite as stupid as I thought.