# Why is autocomplete in PyCharm for Django Templates is not working?

Tags: python, pycharm

Django Model Autocomplete is not working in PyCharm, it worked actually a week ago and now it stopped [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUd5C.png)

I wanted to have all model attributes as it should be but it's not working. Tried to Reset IDE settings - still the same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677670/why-isnt-pycharms-autocomplete-working-for-libraries-i-install
please see this answer

Comment: The thing is that Autocomplete is not working only for the Model Concept in HTML file. In other cases - it works

Comment: may be it will help you (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35229/Autocomplete-for-html-files-not-working-in-PyCharm)[click to see further details]

Comment: No, it's not, because the HTML autocomplete is working, Django Model Autocomplete isn't working

Answer (score 0):

finally I found it. Just go the pycharm `settings`, Click on `Editor`.

[image]

Here you can see the `code completion`. Just scroll down. Now you can see in pitcher and as well as `SQL`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did as you said but nothing change, still no dropdown with options to choose in HTML template

Comment: i just add an picture in my answer, please verify it

Comment: Nothing changed...

Comment: do you have professional edition?

Comment: PyCharm 2023.1.5

Comment: i mean you have community edition..?

Comment: I think yes, I found JSON file in program folder, which say me this:
"name": "PyCharm",
"version": "2023.1.5",
"buildNumber": "231.9414.12",
"productCode": "PY",
"dataDirectoryName": "PyCharm2023.1",
"svgIconPath": "bin/pycharm.svg",
"productVendor": "JetBrains",

Comment: If it help, I've decided to continue to work, and in HTML files it's not seeing not only model suggestions but also - if statements, and other. For example : 
When you type {% if page.has_next %} and you start typing if page. - it doesnt show you all suggestions you have to type manually